# gsutil rename files as they are being copied from different directories

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

I have three folders in a storage bucket, each containing `test_result_0.xml`:

- `gs://test-lab-12345-67890/2018-02-23_18:48:45.403202_urtc/Nexus6P-27-en_US-portrait/test_result_0.xml`
- `gs://test-lab-12345-67890/2018-02-23_18:48:45.403202_urtc/Nexus7-21-en_US-portrait/test_result_0.xml`
- `gs://test-lab-12345-67890/2018-02-23_18:48:45.403202_urtc/Nexus6P-23-en_US-portrait/test_result_0.xml`

Now I'm looking to copy them into a local folder, and rename them to something like:

- `test_result_0.xml`
- `test_result_1.xml`
- `test_result_2.xml`

What is the best way to go about doing that, using a bash script? I have this so far, but it doesn't work :(

`` for i in $("`gsutil ls gs://test-lab-12345-67890 | tail -1`*/*.xml"); do 
    gsutil -m cp -r -U $i ~/Documents
done ``

Comment: A few observations. First, the paths listed at the top of the message are all the same. Second, in the $("`...`") construct, the shell will construct the "..." string and then attempt to execute it. Maybe start with one gsutil cp -r to a local directory and do the renames locally.

Comment: Thanks - I got it and will post answer

Answer (score 2):

Solved it using something like this:

```html
counter=0
for path in $(gsutil ls -r gs://test-lab-12345-67890/**/*.xml | tail -3); do
 counter=$((counter+1))
 gsutil -m cp -r -U $path ~/localpath
 mv ~/localpath/test_result_0.xml ~/localpath/test_result_$counter.xml
done
```

Not the most pretty code but it works for now .. unless someone can offer me a better way to do it? :)

Edit: Turns out in the documentation (which I missed) you can specify:

- `--results-bucket=RESULTS_BUCKET]`
- `--results-dir=RESULTS_DIR`

So that completely alleviates the problem I'm having since I'm now able to specify the folder names in advance!! I will keep the old code up for reference.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/firebase/test/android/run

Answer (score 1):

I tried to improve your solution making use of [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). 
Check if you prefer this kind of solution, I do not know if you consider it more "elegant":

```
gsutil ls -r gs://test-lab-12345-67890/**/test_result_* | awk -F"/" {'system("gsutil cp "$0" ~/localpath/"$6)'}
```

In my test environment works with a file and folder structure similar to yours.

**P.S.** I didn't use many of the gsutils flags you used in your solution to improve readability, but you can add them if you think they are needed.